# Tag / challenge type proposal: Size coding

Tags: discussion, challenges, scoring, new-genre

This question and proposal is different from [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7323/42643) one, since this proposal includes a scoring mechanism that is vastly different from [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### What is size coding?

Size coding as a form of competetion has been established in 1998 by HUGI (a [demoscene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene) e-zine). The competitions ("compos") have been organized regularly since 1998 up until 2009. You can review a history of challenges, rules and entries [here](http://www.hugi.scene.org/compo/compoold.htm).

### How are they scored?

> in  this  competition you are supposed to try  to create an exe- or a com-file
>   whose  size is as small as possible. the  winner will be the one whose com- or
>   exe-file has the smallest number of bytes.

Even though the source code **had** to be included, the scoring would only be affected by the size of the binary submitted by the answerer in bytes.

**To further prevent confusion: The entry consists of one single, binary file. The code or methods that were used to generate this binary are irrelevant. The contestants submit their single file, the host will run and score this file. There is no compiling involved (by the host that is).**

### How should size coding challenges work here?

A challenge carrying the [size-coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size-coding) tag should include the following:

- The rules and forbidden loopholes should be stated as clear as in any other challenge on this site.
- The challenge must include the platforms the author is able to test the binary on (e.g. `x86/64 PE32, SSE3/AVX support, Windows 8.1 Pro` or `x64 ELF, SSE2 support, archlinux`)
- Optionally a date on which the compo ends the scores will be made final

### Why not just "code-golf"?

The main difference here is the scoring by the binary size. The binary is what actually determines a person's score (and thus needs to be tested). This allows quite a few languages to be used, but shifts the focus from creating the shortest possible code, to a higher balance between algorithm optimization *and* coding.

Yes, this also disqualifies almost all golfing langs, but this is not my intention nor my interest.

In the linked question above, Peter Taylor expressed concerns about the "reproduce-ability" of the actual binary code, which is exactly why size coding entries are scored by file size, not code size. You can have very clean and interesting solutions in code, and still win.

### What about VMs?

JVM or IL binaries are usually discouraged, but not excluded if the actual binary can run without any dependencies on the target platform. I will cite the PC compo rules of this year's Revision, because they reflect exactly my stance on this:

> - DotNet Entries: DotNet 4.5.x, part of Windows 8, is available. We will not install any older versions.
> - And in case someone might still have this mad idea: We will not install any drivers or virtual machines to provide or improve DOS compatibility.
> - Java entries are allowed but you need to provide your own runtime in the submitted archive. This runtime will not be installed on the compo machine so you will have to start your production using the command line switches.

The logical consequence is that you'd choose linux as your platform for Java entries (because they might have JVM by default) and Windows for MSIL entries.

### Obsolete hardware that provides advantages

As long as the author can provide a native hardware running the target operating system (no Virtual Machines), they can accept entries for it. E.g. by default, I expect no one to own a PC that actually runs MS-DOS. So even though "approximations" like FreeDOS exist, the latter would not be valid for accepting MS-DOS `COM` entries. (The same way ReactOS can't be used to accept Windows XP entries and so on).

### Why not do X, add Y or even merge this into the challenge type Z?

This is size coding. Everything else pretty much isn't size coding. I want to provide a challenge type for folks who are familiar with actual size coding or still do it. So here's a TL;DR (mainly for *contestants* in a [size-coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size-coding) challenge):

- The score is the byte size of the binary that runs natively, without any additional files or dependencies on the default configuration of any given platform specified by the author.
- Explanation (as code or in words) has to be included.
- Scores should be made final on a given date.

Size coding challenges are pretty much on-topic (there's another question to discuss this), this is a proposal for a challenge standard.

---

Personal thoughts: There are many people interested in actual size coding. I think this site can provide a nice platform for it - without harming other challenge types.

Comment: Dear voters:  Don't vote as to whether you would personally enjoy this scoring mechanism, but vote as to whether or not the mechanism is clear and would work well for our site.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I think those go hand in hand. You wouldn't enjoy it if you didn't think it would work well for the site. :P

Comment: @AlexA. Off-topic challenges usually implies "not enjoyable", but "not enjoyable" doesn't necessarily mean off-topic.

Comment: @AlexA. You can absolutely enjoy things not really fit for this site (like most popcon proposals). This is why there are different challenge types in the first place :D (kinda ninja'd by Nathan).

Comment: Would people be allowed to tweak the binaries by hand? (And if not, what's stopping them from doing it, and if yes, *is* this different from code golf in binary?)

Comment: Although you reference my answer, you don't seem to have understood it at all. The fact that size-coding means that the winning criterion is the size of the binary is precisely why it's a potential problem that different compilers, different versions of the same compiler, or even the same compiler with the same options but using non-deterministic optimisation heuristics might produce different sizes of binary.

Comment: @PeterTaylor This is exactly why this is not the problem. There is *no compiling* involved. The contestants submit *binaries*. How any given binary was created is *completely* irrelevant. A submission consists of one single file.

Comment: So why submit source code? All serious answers are going to be in assembly, and scarcely more readable than the binary.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Where does it say the source code has to be submitted?

Comment: "*While the source code must be included,*"

Comment: @PeterTaylor That is an editing oversight of mine. We dropped that requirement after a recent discussion in chat.

Comment: @mınxomaτ If you dropped that requirement, it isn't different from a normal code-golf with language restrictions (the machine code).

Comment: Also what's the point of the "Scores should be made final on a given date." rule? That seems like any such challenge would (arbitrarily?) be required to have a closing date? That seems to go directly against the spirit of SE as an endeavour to create content of lasting value (which in our case is the challenges). Of course things like fastest code and KotHs tend to have these deadlines but there it's (currently) a practical necessity.

Comment: [rhoScript](http://www.rhoscript.com/)'s CLISP compiler generates bytecode, which can do *8 queens* in *17 bytes*. The runtime needs SBCL, but could be made standalone. Anyways, my point is, this will cause a crop-up of standalone interpreters for specialised golf-bytecode, as opposed to people trying to golf ELF headers.

Comment: @tac the OP mentions that the bytecode has to run in *hardware*, not a vm. If you can find hardware that runs pyth bytecode...

Comment: @Maltysen I'm saying, rhoScript's runtime is SBCL and Lisp, being a very extensible, simple language, with a rhoScript compiler + interpreter could be made into a standalone executable in EXE or ELF format.

Comment: @Maltysen Pyth is a bad example, because it's written in pure Python and Python is written in not-small C. It's possible, however, to make Python into native code, and thus it's possible to make Pyth into native code, and thus it's possible to [tag:sizecoding] pyth :D

Comment: @tac you're misunderstanding. The byteode has to run on hardware. Compiling Pyth with the above chain would result in a huge exe/elf. the same would happen if you include the entire SBCL & Lisp & Rho runtime with the binary.

Comment: @Maltysen Yes, the Pyth-as-EXE would be huge, which is why I said it's a bad example. On the other hand, [mouse-2002](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/) or [mouse16](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16)'s runtimes, if written in FORTH or C, could be really tiny, and those are quite feature-complete langs

Comment: I'm already somewhat scared compiling and running other peoples' C entries for fastest code, because I know they can be harmful even though I can see exactly what I'm compiling. Machine code is much harder to understand at a glance and can be pretty dangerous. Correct me if I'm wrong about any of that, but it seems like a problem

Comment: Try it out. It doesn't seem like it would be off-topic.

Comment: Note also there's GOLF CPU, which is size coding in a way that can be safely run and verified: https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu